# SQL Server - indexing a large table with multiple columns? or one index for every report?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have this table with millions of rows: Recording (Id, CampaignId, CallDateTime, Phone, etc)

And I have 2 different reports on that table:

```
--By Date:
declare @CampaignId int = 1, @Date date = '2023-06-27'
select * from Recording
where CampaignId = @CampaignId and cast(CallDateTime as date) = @Date

--By Phone:
declare @CampaignId int = 1, @Phone varchar(9) = '987654321'
select * from Recording
where CampaignId = @CampaignId and Phone = @Phone
```

It should have index, but how? With multiple columns (CampaignId, CallDateTime, Phone)? Or one index for every report (CampaignId, CallDateTime) and (CampaignId, Phone)?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the maximum number of rows per CampaignId? `select top 1 count(*) as c from Recording where CampaignId is not null group by CampaignId order by c desc`

Comment: Not many, Campaign table has less than 200 rows.

Comment: i would add three indexes: one campaignid, on calldatetime and on phone. One problem is that you cast calldatetime to date, this ruins the SARG-ability. better do a between or something like that without casting

Comment: CampaignId grouped has thousends or 1M-2M rows in the Recording table

Comment: @siggemannen yes I can do a between instead, but why to create 3 indexes for each column?

Comment: Are you really selecitng `*` in all queries? Doing so removes the usefulness of a narrow covering index. What is the existing clustered index?

Comment: this way, sql server has statistics per each column and can use the cardinality of each column to choose the most selective index. For example it knows if campaignId = 100 or date = '20100101' gives least rows and chooses either campaign or date index. We've used this successfully in our databases (those are in TB size with billions of rows).

Comment: A composite index would be better for the queries shown than individual indexes would be. With individual indexes the best it can do from each seek is narrow down based on one column. Having individual indexes might also support other queries that you haven't shown but if in fact you never are just filtering on date without CampaignId  there is no point creating such an index

Comment: What other columns are there? Do you need them all? Please provide the full definition of your table. You probably want two indexes, but each needs `INCLUDE` columns for the other columns being selected.

Comment: @siggemannen Three separate indexes is not the way. Neither the calldatetime nor the phone index in that proposal would ever be used by these queries.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should fix the first query, or no index will be useful.  It should be:

```
--By Date:
declare @CampaignId int = 1, @Date date = '2023-06-27'
select * from Recording
where CampaignId = @CampaignId 
and CallDateTime >= @Date
and CallDateTime < dateadd(day,1,@Date)
```

The general rule is never wrap the column in an expresson; always write the query so the parameter is instead.  And check the [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to ensure that the column won't have to be converted to the parameter's type.  Here Datetime is higher than Date, so no explicit conversion on the parameter is needed.

Next, start with the a single useful clustered index, perhaps (CampaignId,CallDateTime).  This will give you an optimal plan for the first query and a reasonable plan for the second query.

If you have millions of rows and lots of different reporting queries that would require many different indexes for optimal performance, consider adding a non-clustered or clustered [columnstore index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver16).  This switches to columnar storage with the highest compression and fastest scan rate.  With a columnstore you don't need the perfect index for each reporting query because scanning a few million rows in a columnstore is *really fast*.

Answer (score 0):

To create a good index for one query:

- Start with column(s) tested with `=`
- After that, you can add another column

  where CampaignId = @CampaignId
  and CallDateTime >= @Date
  and CallDateTime  < dateadd(day,1,@Date)

As David pointed out, making the tests Sargable is important.  Then

```
(CampaignId, CallDateTime)   -- In this order
```

For this:

```
where CampaignId = @CampaignId and Phone = @Phone
```

have

```
(CampaignId, Phone)  -- The order is not important
```

Neither index is very useful for the other query.  Make the optimal index for each query, then see if some indexes are the same or similar enough.

For example:  `INDEX(a,b,c)` will work fine for a query that needs `INDEX(a,b)`